# Loading a DLL from within a JAR file

Tags: java

I want to use System.load() to load a DLL file that is within the JAR.
I tried

```
URL dllPath = MyClass.class.getResource("path/to/dll/folder");
System.load(dllPath.getPath().replace("file:/","")+"/"+dllName);
```

I get:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: path/to/jar/thejar.jar!/path/to/dll

Any ideas?

Comment: What makes you think that path including `!` and relative path within the JAR archive is understood by the method? I would expect it to only accept filesystem paths.

Comment: this function gives me the right path, its system.load() who apparently can't access to a ressource in a jar file, idk why

Comment: @wil That's correct, because it's not a path on the file system. A file inside the JAR archive is not accessible with just a path, you need to extract it to temp and pass the path of the temp file to `System.load`

Comment: How do I extract the dll to a temporary file ?

Comment: @wil Have a look [here](https://github.com/adamheinrich/native-utils/blob/master/src/main/java/cz/adamh/utils/NativeUtils.java)

Comment: thank you BackSlash

Comment: Look here: https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipeNo031